# Python Daemon Error

Tags: python, debian, python-daemon

I'm trying to make a python script to run as daemon, and I'm facing this problem when try to import the runner model:

```
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Dec 27 2010, 00:02:40) 
[GCC 4.4.5] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from daemon import runner
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/python_daemon-1.5.5-py2.6.egg/daemon/runner.py", line 25, in <module>
    import pidlockfile
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/python_daemon-1.5.5-py2.6.egg/daemon/pidlockfile.py", line 33, in <module>
    class PIDLockFile(LinkFileLock, object):
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    function() argument 1 must be code, not str
```

I'm programming under Debian 6.0, and installed the python-daemon and lockfile manually and via apt, but nothing changed. Any idea?

Regards,,,

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the version of `python-daemon` is incompatible with the version of `lockfile`. This can happen on pypi. If you do not care about a recent version, remove the manually installed versions of both and rely on the `python-daemon` package. As long as you see `/usr/local` in the traceback, you are not using Debian's version.